# Is it better to declare a function with or without var?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

There are two ways I've seen people declare functions in javascript. Either:

```
foo = function()
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

or

```
var foo = function()
{
  //Do stuff
}
```

I'm new to javascript, and would like to know if there is a real difference between the two. Is one better to use than the other, or does it depend on the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Declaring it in a variable
- Using the default function declaration

In your case, you're trying to declare it in a variable. Declaring variables (whether function or not) start with the `var` syntax.

```
var foo = function() { }; // please note that semicolon (;)
```

When defining a function normally:

```
function foo() { }
```

So, again, in your case, the `var` is required, unless you pre-define it:

```
var foo;
foo = function() { };
```

Edit: As James stated, if you wish to define it in the global scope you can discard the `var` keyword. But to be honest it's still a better practise to predefine the variable if you wish to define it on another scope level.

Comment: `var` is not *required* but should be used.

Comment: @FelixKling I just edited my post ;)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, if you do not state `var` then your function will be assigned to the global scope (same scope level as the `window` object), however if you declare it as `var` it will be contained within its parent scope.

EDIT: to clarify after the response from Tomalak, the function will belong to its parent scope, however if the parent scope is a function which is executed, after execution of the enclosing function, any functions declared without var will be accessible within the global context.

Comment: That's not true. A function will always be contained in its parent scope.

Comment: @Tomalak you are correct, that was an error on my part

Answer (score 0):

It's better to declare with `var`, otherwise you may be affecting any other var within the **global scope**. Check for example this question for more information: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)